# Is it possible to extract generic arguments of a type as an array/tuple from an array/tuple of generic types?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, tuples, typescript-generics

I want to create a function that takes an array of generic functions and "zips" them into a single function that takes all of the input functions' arguments and returns all of the outputs of those functions in a single call. The only way I was able to make it type-safe is with `infer`'ing each generic functions' individual component:

```js
type Fn<T = any, TReturn = any> = (arg: T) => TReturn;

type FnArg<T extends Fn> = T extends Fn<infer TArg> ? TArg : unknown;
type FnArgTuple<T extends Fn[]> = { [key in keyof T]: FnArg<T[key]> };

type FnReturn<T extends Fn> = T extends Fn<any, infer TReturn> ? TReturn : unknown;
type FnReturnTuple<T extends Fn[]> = { [key in keyof T]: FnReturn<T[key]> };

const fnZip = <T extends ((arg: any) => any)[]>(
  fns: [...T],
): Fn<FnArgTuple<T>, FnReturnTuple<T>> => (
  args,
) => fns.map((fn, idx) => fn(args[idx])) as FnReturnTuple<T>;
```

However, I was wondering whether there was more elegant and/or idiomatic way to extract functions' arguments and return types as tuples from a given array of functions. Here's a (non-working) illustration of what I mean:

```js
type Fn<T = any, TReturn = any> = (arg: T) => TReturn;

const fnZip = <T extends any[], TReturn extends any[]>(
  fns: { [key: number]: Fn<T[key], TReturn[key]> },
): Fn<T, TReturn> => (args) => fns.map((fn, idx) => fn(args[idx])) as TReturn;
```

---

EDIT: What I effectively want to express is the following:

```
[Type<A1, B1>, Type<A2, B2>, ...etc] => Type<[A1, A2, ..etc], [B1, B2, ...etc]>
```

---

EDIT: [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191363/is-it-possible-to-extract-generic-arguments-of-a-type-as-an-array-tuple-from-an/76194591#comment134363519_76191363) proposed a solution that would've worked perfectly if TS could infer the second generic type correctly, but it doesn't for unknown reason:

```
type Fn<T = any, TReturn = any> = (arg: T) => TReturn;

const fnZip = <T extends any[], TReturn extends { [key in keyof T]: any }>(
  fns: [...{ [key in keyof T]: Fn<T[key], TReturn[key]> }],
): Fn<T, TReturn> => (args) => fns.map((fn, idx) => fn(args[idx])) as TReturn;

const zipped = fnZip([
//     ^? const zipped: Fn<[string, number], [any, any]>
  (x: string) => x.length,
  (y: number) => y.toFixed(),
]);
```

Comment: I don't see how you're "composing" the functions; you're building an array of return values with `.map()` and not applying the output of one function as the input of the next.

Comment: @Pointy my terminology here may be shoddy, I won't deny that. Maybe "zipping" is more appropriate? The term used, however, doesn't change my fundamental issue

Comment: As far as I know there's nothing more elegant *that also works the way you want*; presumably you want the return type of the functions to be inferred contextually (it would have been nice for you to provide a [mre] of how you want to call `compose` or... `zipApply` or whatever we should call it) so I'm just guessing here), but the compiler doesn't want to split the inference that way. (*more*…)

Comment: (… *continued*) [See this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w22G9w) to see what happens.  My working version is essentially the same as yours, more or less, I mostly just didn't create a bunch of one-time-use utility types for it.  Does this fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this is what I was looking for! I tried your approach earlier, but got stuck on how to use key from `T` (`A` in your example) on `TReturn` (`B` in your example), since I used `any[]` constraint on both argument part and return part. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, wait, it doesn't fully work... Nevermind :c. Thank you for taking a look, anyway

Comment: So what should we do to proceed here?  Not sure what "never mind" means in the context of my previous two comments.

Comment: Would you mind telling me what we should do to proceed? Now that you’ve taken my comment and folded it into the question, I’m not sure if the scope has changed or what.  Ideally I’d like to know whether any of my suggestions constitute what you’d consider an answer, in which case I’ll write it up and link to documentation and sources… or if it doesn’t, in which case I’ll disengage.  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz Sorry I left you hanging, I was just trying to look for help in other places, but so far have failed to find any improvement over your suggestion... I guess I'll accept your answer for now, and come back to this question if anything change, say, in future versions of TS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "elegant" answer to your question is to use two [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, corresponding to the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `A` of function argument types and the tuple `R` of their corresponding return types, and then the input `fns` would be a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) over one of these (say, `A`):

```
const fnZip = <A extends any[], R extends { [I in keyof A]: any }>(
  fns: [...{ [I in keyof A]: Fn<A[I], R[I]> }],
): Fn<A, R> => (args) => fns.map((fn, idx) => fn(args[idx])) as R;
```

(Well, it's actually a mapped type wrapped in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to prompt the compiler to infer a tuple type for `A` instead of some unordered array type of arbitrary length.)

That version "works", in the sense that if you manually specify the `A` and `R` type arguments, you'll get the expected output:

```
const zipped = fnZip<[string, number], [number, string]>(
  [x => x.length, y => y.toFixed(2)]
);
// const zipped: Fn<[string, number], [number, string]>
```

But if you'd like the type arguments to be *inferred*, you're going to have a bad time:

```
const zipped = fnZip([(x: string) => x.length, (y: number) => y.toFixed(2)]);
// const zipped: Fn<[string, number], [any, any]>
```

Here `A` is inferred correctly but `R` is not.  That's because inference from mapped types only infers the type whose properties you're mapping over.  Since `fns`'s type maps over the keys of `A`, only `A` can get properly inferred.  `R` ends up falling back to the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

You can switch to `R` instead of `A` but that just moves the problem:

```
const fnZip = <A extends { [I in keyof R]: any }, R extends any[]>(
  fns: [...{ [I in keyof R]: Fn<A[I], R[I]> }],
): Fn<A, R> => (args) => fns.map((fn, idx) => fn(args[idx])) as R;


const zipped = fnZip2([(x: string) => x.length, (y: number) => y.toFixed(2)]);
// const zipped: Fn<[any, any], [number, string]>
```

You could try to make it a mapped type over both `A` and `R` at once somehow, but everything I tried either didn't help or caused at least one compiler error somewhere, and the quotation marks around the word "elegant" were becoming more and more sarcastic as I tried different and weirder things.  Here's the closest I could get:

```
const fnZip = <A extends { [I in keyof R]: any } & any[], R extends { [I in keyof A]: any }>(
  fns: [...{ [I in keyof (A & R)]: Fn<A[I], R[I]> }], // error! 
  // -> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // A rest element type must be an array type.(2574)
): Fn<A, R> => (args) => fns.map((fn, idx) => fn(args[idx])) as R;

const zipped = fnZip([(x: string) => x.length, (y: number) => y.toFixed(2)]);
// const zipped: Fn<[string, number], [number, string]>
```

Here the inference works, hooray!  But the call signature causes a compiler error I can't resolve without breaking the inference.

For now, this doesn't quite look possible.  Even if I found a way that worked I'd be worried that it'd be too fragile to rely on.  This is at or beyond the edge of TypeScript's abilities right now.

---

Instead I think it's much more straightforward to make the inference work out by doing the simple thing of having `fns`'s type be the type parameter `F` or `[...F]`, and then spend a little effort unrolling that into `A` and `R`.  Like you've done, or like this:

```
const fnZip = <F extends ((arg: any) => any)[]>(
  fns: [...F]
) => (args: { [I in keyof F]: Parameters<F[I]>[0] }) =>
    fns.map((fn, idx) => fn(args[idx])) as
    { [I in keyof F]: ReturnType<F[I]> };
```

And it's a judgment call but I wouldn't say it's *that* inelegant.  And it has the benefit of actually working:

```
const zipped = fnZip([(x: string) => x.length, (y: number) => y.toFixed(2)]);
// const z: (args: [string, number]) => [number, string]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.0.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgC4CeMyAYsADwCCANEgEoB8SAvEgBQgBOAcwBcSOgEpO7ZgG58hJKEiwEyAKIYIAkMGIBJKAAsAQgFc9wAGYQ+EYIkogAlhih45RIvAD2wKMSQWwABajjCcSPRIEAAexLYAJq7apADaALpMzFGxCa64SCm6SI7ASADWEKReFqJpIslIAL6s3PIeAb4iKQB0vfmFxaUVVTV0dUjU9IUZLNPsjRltSGIik4ws7BzsvIJQElsdUN1gIDDc3IFMjvHR++yBOwJQKdfRaWISIK4y7h7evv4sKEKPEABJgMDhQIhGA0FJ+PglARMYAmMAAI2sMxSqIx1iYCKRaRaSyIKWikiQ0W6GmAAmIBiYpEppG6xC8lEc0Qg8W4ACYxGklmJZO0APRipD-PxIIEwEHgsCrWjw4iIukotGYvjY3HaglqomsX6eHwyuUgqHBULcFLcaIiQl0u5Umm2emMnikER66wu1nsznc3kC96ijwSqVmwHAnnKuFO5EKLVYpgpZJMZLEpCAXg3AHI7v0av0U0DgiCQABU+KQsgQltL-NDQuFIjE4sBEngCkUSuVKtUWOMGo1Mtl253kukSe0iIEoF1et1+j2hv2asxxmtppk5k1Fu0VhNaOs2JTHntKXPjqdzpdijcXQ9+E8Xjd3p9vrITVGAbLY-ErRhW17UdQ1nUpalaQ9JhuG9ZM8T4f02Q5LkeX5QURSWSMGz-eU4yPOEMyQLM019PgDXVARs3zeQi3kEtlHLKtSCMLwGTcetow6GEWzoMdci7AZe2GAcN3qYBmUaJAADJiIk9JRzbATl0GPsRlqcTJOnGc5wXPpu1UkSam4PjZOYQV4zobdZl0bMFiYSNrD4Lw+AAQiQUkkEjPibBlCANEgHQSHIZAwBMGVMTk4i+D4EBmTIChun5ABWAB2AAWMRhUszJNm2Z8LwOK8TjOC5gCuB9L2Ac9XzeD5iM-b8cItHlAJtO0HSQRMXUg90GRguCyKQwNUJDDDwyIbCuJa+J41VSjNQQ3UU3IrqwKo9gc0AWR3C3kejwFLFQkAAdRcsokQ49ocKbMIuBoSh+I7VxzmfTSXWSMQp1aGdDj07pKCFA8zwKkQVOEtcJnGAAFfgDriPgoHuuYUgABjSJo7k82dfGvUq71eR9qoK2r3warHBJXNSBwBkRmAgYgTD4YAKxCpHbPmL8rum-82rODrQMonq3TpfqvR9FbhpQ4N0LDLDJWakRzy6RNFu1d5KRxFaKKJXNACE9zjfxsfwuBm20ACIQHReAzaYABZEAGW6KHbMwrnfC8DQaS8ARuCNiRIxSABmJgzcD7oAEZ0rNoVaLkRogA)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safe to say the answer is no.

And I say that because Ben Lesh, and the brilliant people he works with to create and improve RXJS don't have a great answer either despite RXJS being wildly popular, open source code.

So if there was an elegant solution, they'd adopt it.

Instead, (as of 7-MAY-2023), [their solution](https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/tree/7.8.1/src/internal/util/pipe.ts#L71-L80) is a brute-force method of overloading, 0 through 9 arguments, and then for the 10th argument onward the code is "now we're getting silly so just make sure they're single-parameter functions and call that good enough!"

```js
import { identity } from './identity';
import { UnaryFunction } from '../types';

export function pipe(): typeof identity;
export function pipe<T, A>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>): UnaryFunction<T, A>;
export function pipe<T, A, B>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>): UnaryFunction<T, B>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C>(fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>, fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>, fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>): UnaryFunction<T, C>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D>(
  fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>,
  fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>,
  fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>,
  fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>
): UnaryFunction<T, D>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E>(
  fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>,
  fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>,
  fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>,
  fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>,
  fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>
): UnaryFunction<T, E>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F>(
  fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>,
  fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>,
  fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>,
  fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>,
  fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>,
  fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>
): UnaryFunction<T, F>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(
  fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>,
  fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>,
  fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>,
  fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>,
  fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>,
  fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>,
  fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>
): UnaryFunction<T, G>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(
  fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>,
  fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>,
  fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>,
  fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>,
  fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>,
  fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>,
  fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>,
  fn8: UnaryFunction<G, H>
): UnaryFunction<T, H>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(
  fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>,
  fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>,
  fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>,
  fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>,
  fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>,
  fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>,
  fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>,
  fn8: UnaryFunction<G, H>,
  fn9: UnaryFunction<H, I>
): UnaryFunction<T, I>;
export function pipe<T, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(
  fn1: UnaryFunction<T, A>,
  fn2: UnaryFunction<A, B>,
  fn3: UnaryFunction<B, C>,
  fn4: UnaryFunction<C, D>,
  fn5: UnaryFunction<D, E>,
  fn6: UnaryFunction<E, F>,
  fn7: UnaryFunction<F, G>,
  fn8: UnaryFunction<G, H>,
  fn9: UnaryFunction<H, I>,
  ...fns: UnaryFunction<any, any>[]
): UnaryFunction<T, unknown>;

/**
 * pipe() can be called on one or more functions, each of which can take one argument ("UnaryFunction")
 * and uses it to return a value.
 * It returns a function that takes one argument, passes it to the first UnaryFunction, and then
 * passes the result to the next one, passes that result to the next one, and so on.  
 */
export function pipe(...fns: Array<UnaryFunction<any, any>>): UnaryFunction<any, any> {
  return pipeFromArray(fns);
}

/** @internal */
export function pipeFromArray<T, R>(fns: Array<UnaryFunction<T, R>>): UnaryFunction<T, R> {
  if (fns.length === 0) {
    return identity as UnaryFunction<any, any>;
  }

  if (fns.length === 1) {
    return fns[0];
  }

  return function piped(input: T): R {
    return fns.reduce((prev: any, fn: UnaryFunction<T, R>) => fn(prev), input as any);
  };
}
```

My advice to you is to use RXJS's solution instead of writing your own. If their code was insufficient then they'd have changed it. Also, if you're already using RXJS as a dependency, or don't mind including it, then you'll get any improvements automatically.

Comment: What I *don't* understand in this code is why they aren't recursive here. I would have expected there to be a good way to say something like `type PipeArgs<A,Z> = [UnaryFunction<A,Z>] | [UnaryFunction<A,B>, ...PipeArgs<B,Z>]`??

Comment: @JSmart532 Interesting question. There are many ways to just grab the first argument of the first function and the return type of the last function and return a function signature that has the former as input and the latter as output, but I couldn't get the mid-way suggestions to work. I.e. when you type functions into `pipe`, you only really need to specify the first function's argument type, then TS would infer the output of that function and "pipe" it to the next function, without needing to specify anything further